# Get Last ID of element

Tags: jquery

This gets the ID of element that contains a value, select, or checked. However, I'm trying to identify the **LAST** ID that contains a value, select or check within a form.

Any solutions how to solve for this would be a big help!

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/be16dyyk/10/)

```js
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
  $(".analytics").each(function() {
    var getid = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).is('input:text') && $(this).val() != "") {
      alert(getid);
    } else if ($(this).is('select') && $(this).val() != "") {
      alert(getid);
      return false;
    } else if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert(getid);
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a value at the top and a value at the bottom and submit</p>

<form id="myForm">
  1) Please Select Your First Car
  <BR>
  <select id="car1" class="analytics">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <BR>
  <BR>2) Please Select Your Second Car
  <BR>
  <select id="car2" class="analytics">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>3) First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="analytics" value="">
  <BR>
  <BR>4) Last name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="analytics">

  <br>
  <br>5) Select your Newsletter:
  <BR>
  <input type="checkbox" id="news1" name="newsletter" value="" class="analytics">Daily
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="news2" name="newsletter" value="" class="analytics">Weekly
  <br>
  <br>6) Select your Gender:
  <BR>
  <input type="radio" id="gender1" name="gender" value="" class="analytics">Male
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="gender2" name="gender" value="" class="analytics">Female
  <br>
  <br>7) Do you like books?
  <BR>
  <input type="radio" id="question_yes" name="question" value="" class="analytics">Yes
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="question_no" name="question" value="" class="analytics">No
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What does "LAST ID" mean?  Do you mean you want the CSS id of the last element in a form that is not empty?  If so, what exactly is your criteria for not empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.last`](https://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
    // Retrieve the last element with inputs
    var $last = $(".analytics").filter(function() {

        // Filter based on the same filters you're already using
        return ($(this).is('input:text') && $(this).val() != "") ||
            ($(this).is('select') && $(this).val() != "") ||
            $(this).is(':checked');
    }).last()

    alert($last.attr("id"));
    return false
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/be16dyyk/13/)**

I would also suggest using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for attaching events, especially since [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated (*and removed!*) from later versions of jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you mean....

Get the total number of form elements. Then iterate through the elements backwards. Like this....

```
var i = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.length;

var count = i;
while(count > 0)
{
    if(document.getElementById("myForm").elements[count].value)
    {
        alert("Found it!! ID: " + document.getElementById("myForm").elements[count].id);
    }
    count--;
}
```